# Verification email when new Acumos user registers not received

Tags: acumos

According to the documentation, new users should receive an email verification email from Acumos when registering. On our newly deployed Acumos instance this is not the case. I have verified that using *mail -s "Test mail setup" xxxxx@gmail.com*  (CLI command) from the Ubuntu 16.04 server VM where Acumos has been installed works. Any hints on what might be the problem?

I have also tried to use the "Forgot password" functionality to see if that triggers sending and reception of an email but it did not work either. New users are nevertheless allowed to sign in.

**Update**:

After receiving comments I added the suggested entries for mail (smtp) in AIO/docker/acumos/portal-be.yml. I then recreated the portal-be service using the command *bash docker-compose.sh up -d --build portal-be-service* from the AIO folder. The docker-compose command regenerated the Docker image (with the new config) and starts it up again. I can now get emails from the Acumos portal :-)

```
            \"portal\": {
               \"feature\": {
                  \"publishSelfRequestEnabled\": \"false\",
                  \"validateModel\": \"false\",
                  \"email_service\": \"smtp\",
```

....

```
            \"spring\": {
               \"mail\" : {
                  \"host\" : \"smtphost.tele.no\",
                  \"port\" : 25,
                  \"username\" : \"arneme\",
                  \"password\" : \"xxxxxxxx\",  # Real password removed and substituted with xxxxxxxx (do not want to disclose password on stackoverflow)
                  \"debug\" : \"true\",
                  \"smtp\" : {
                     \"starttls\" : {
                        \"enable\" : \"true\"
                     },
                     \"auth\" : \"false\"
                  },
                  \"transport\" : {
                     \"protocol\" : \"smtp\"
                  },
                  \"template\" : {
                     \"folder\" : {
                        \"path\" : \"/fmtemplates/\"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
```

Comment: You have configured "email_service": "mail"?  Please use "smtp" as the value of that key instead, I should have been more clear.

Comment: OK, changed to smtp but can still not receive emails. No email related errors reported in portal-be debug or error logs (/var/acumos/logs) nor in container log (docker logs acumos_portal-be-servicexxxx). I changed the entry above to reflect the new setting

Comment: There are two places to configure: you tell portal the name of the email service, which must be "smtp" in this case, and there's another whole block with all the configuration for that email service, which is fixed to use key "mail". Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to configure the mail service correct in the portal-be.yml file. The configuration example in the "Update" is the way it needs to be. I had placed the latter part in the "portal" section instead of in the "spring" section.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: hi Arne, maybe I can suggest that you accept one of our answers, rather than your note thanking us for answers?

Comment: Yes, that was my plan, but stackoverflow will not allow me to do that until later today for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the critical configuration item here is the "email_service" item within the portal-be block. If no email service is configured, then it's probably not going to work. Our test labs use service type "mailjet" and if you look deeper in that docker-compose config you will see mailjet configuration keys.

```
"portal" : {
    "feature" : {
       "email_service" : "",
       ...
```

**Update 1:** Our portal-be expert provided config details so you can use "smtp" as the value of the email_service, like this:

```
"portal" : {
    "feature" : {
       "email_service" : "smtp",
       ...
```

And you'll need to configure it properly.  I quote:

> Here is the smtp property set up example

```
"spring" : {
    "mail" : {
        "host" : "PROVIDE YOUR HOSTNAME",
        "port" : 25,
        "username" : "PROVIDE YOUR USERNAME",
        "password" : "PROVIDE YOUR PASSWORD",
        "debug" : "true",
            "smtp" : {
                "starttls" : {
                    "enable" : "true"
                },
                "auth" : "false"
            },
            "transport" : {
                 "protocol" : "smtp"
            },
            "template" : {
                "folder" : {
                    "path" : "/fmtemplates/"
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

This fragment of config must be incorporated in the larger block set in the SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON environment variable by the deployment config, whether docker-compose or K8S.

**Update 2:** trying to correct your entries, here's what they should be. First one:

```
      \"portal\": {
           \"feature\": {
              \"publishSelfRequestEnabled\": \"false\",
              \"validateModel\": \"false\",
              \"email_service\": \"smtp\",
```

Second one:

```
    \"spring\": {
           \"mail\" : {
              \"host\" : \"smtphost.tele.no\",
              \"port\" : 25,
              \"username\" : \"arneme\",
        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

The signup/reminder mail process depends upon some Spring environment configuration values for the Portal-BE and an external mail service account from which the emails will be sent. Once you have set these values, you will need to restart the Portal-BE service e.g. with "sudo docker-compose.sh up -d --build portal-be-service" (assuming you are using the AIO toolset and are in the folder AIO/docker). This part of the AIO tools is evolving so the command above may be slightly different for the version you are using, e.g. "sudo docker-compose.sh $AIO_ROOT up -d --build portal-be-service" where $AIO_ROOT is the path to the AIO folder.

I have not verified with my own mail services but I do know it works, since it's setup correctly in our internal development env. The env variables are set in the docker/kubernetes templates for the Portal-BE, under the SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON env parameter. Supported mail services are "mailjet" and "smtp". The following example is for mailjet (https://www.mailjet.com/).

```
       SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{
            "portal" : {
               "feature" : {
                  "email_service" : "mailjet",
               "mailjet" : {
                  "api" : {
                     "key" : "<your API key>"
                  },
                  "secret" : {
                     "key" : "<your secret key>" 
                  },
                  "address" : {
                     "from" : "<your send-from email address>"
                  }
               },
```

The following example is for SMTP:

```
       SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{
            "spring" : {
               "mail" : {
                  "host" : "Provide the hostname",
                  "port" : 25,
                  "username" : "username",
                  "password" : "password",
                  "debug" : "true",
                  "smtp" : {
                     "starttls" : {
                        "enable" : "true"
                     },
                     "auth" : "false"
                  },
                  "transport" : {
                     "protocol" : "smtp"
                  },
                  "template" : {
                     "folder" : {
                        "path" : "/fmtemplates/"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
```